# Emergency Call: no way to detect and help user

Tags: android, telephony

My application blocks unwanted calls and accidentally it can prevent an emergency service to call back.

To solve this much critical issue I should be able to detect outgoing emergency call immediately when it just dialed and stop my call blocking activities instantly. Yes, actually I can detect outgoing call listening to phone off-hook events, but I can check if it was an emergency call only after it recorded in the CallLog. This helps a bit, but doesn't solve the issue.

Perhaps, not only a telephony application would be safer if it can detect an emergency call and suspend it's activities. We have "onLowMemory ()", why not to have "onEmergencyCall()".

Would appreciate any advice to help this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` event has an extra called `PHONE_NUMBER` that holds the outgoing number.

Comment: +1 for answering his question without him really noticing... :)